# Are the following conversions from DFAs to GNFAs correct?

Tags: finite-state-machine

[image]

This machine (a) should accept all strings that start with a 1 and end with a 0.

[image]

This machine (b) should accept all strings that contain three or more 1s.

[image]

This machine (c) should accept all strings that contain 0101.

Comment: The green squares contain the stages that I avoid in the next step.

Comment: Please post the images within the question, i.e., using the image upload tool. Your Google Drive links don't work for me, they say "You need access" and ask me to request access from you.

Comment: ok I am very sorry I will try to correct...I first tried the upload tool but the images were too big...